# VB Com Error for Naming Sheets on a Worksheet

Tags: vb.net, excel, com-interop, vba

I keep getting an error that says

> "An unhandled exception of type
>   'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in
>   Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll"
>
> Additional information: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

on the line where I'm trying to change the name of the sheets from Workbook reportApp. On my timeWorkbook there are headings in cells A1, then cell D1, and so on.

I want it to loop until there is no more values, but I can't change the name. I can change the name of the sheets in that workbook if I put reportApp.Sheets(s).Name = "Name this sheet", but I don't want to do that. I was wondering if there was any problem with my type or code that would get around this?

```
Private Sub generateReportButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles generateReportButton.Click
    Dim timeApp As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application
    Dim timeClockPath As String = "C:\Users\njryn_000\Desktop\Project ACC\Clock-In Excel\TimeClock.xlsx"
    Dim timeWorkbook As Excel.Workbook = timeApp.Workbooks.Open(timeClockPath, ReadOnly:=False, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True, Editable:=True)
    Dim timeWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet = timeWorkbook.Worksheets("TA")

    Dim reportApp As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application
    Dim reportPath As String = "C:\Users\njryn_000\Desktop\Project ACC\Report\Blank Timecard Report9.xlsx"
    Dim reportWorkbook As Excel.Workbook = reportApp.Workbooks.Open(reportPath, ReadOnly:=False, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended:=True, Editable:=True)
    Dim reportWorksheet As Excel.Worksheet = reportWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet" & 1)

    Dim s As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim f As Integer

    Dim taName As String
    Dim taID As String
    i = 0
    f = 0
    s = 1


    With timeWorksheet.Range("A1")

        Do
            i += 3
            s += 1

            reportApp.Sheets(s).Name = timeWorksheet.Range("A1").Offset(0, i).Value



        Loop Until IsNothing(timeWorksheet.Range("A1").Offset(0, 0).Offset(0, i).Value)
```

Comment: Can you screenshot what the data is in the worksheet?  I suspect that what you are trying to set the worksheet name to is not valid.

Comment: I just figured it out actually, I had to put Val(timeWorksheet.Range("A1").Offset(0, i).Value). Right now i'm actually trying to figure out how to delete "Sheet1" on the reportApp workbook, but it won't work now.

Comment: Looking at your code again, it seems it is VB.Net.  You should add that tag if thats the case.  And if its not *really* VBA consider removing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've already solved your problem but you may not be able to add an answer yet so here is some feedback.

When you use a `With` block you can then refer to whatever you referenced at the top of that block with a single dot ('.') after that.  Its a syntax which reduces writing the same thing over and over.  In the snippet below I've removed all references to `timeWorksheet.Range("A1")` and added a leading dot.

```
With timeWorksheet.Range("A1")

    Do
        i += 3
        s += 1

        ' Since you are using a With block this statement is simplified.
        reportApp.Sheets(s).Name = .Offset(0, i).Value

    ' I removed the .Offset(0, 0) as it is redundant.  
    ' If you have it in to solve a bug you can put it back.
    Loop Until IsNothing(.Offset(0, i).Value)

    ' More code here...
End With
```

Also you've realised that you can use the [`Val()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7beh1x9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function to fix your code.  Reading the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k7beh1x9%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), it explains that this function will take a string and begin reading a number from it, ignoring whitespace.  As soon as it reaches a non-numeric, non-whitespace character it stops and returns the number ignoring whatever else is in the string.

It seems that this isn't really solving your problem, it just works around it.  I'd look at what other characters are present in the cells you are looping through and deal with them explicitly.  Otherwise you might end up with strange results.